# Convert Hair Curves to Bezier Curves

Tags: bezier-curves, hair

I would like to convert the curves generated by Blender's 3.5 hair system to regular Bezier curves... can it be done?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I guess you first need to convert to mesh, then bezier curves

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I know, you first need to convert your hair to meshes, in the *Modifier* panel > *Particle System* modifier > *Convert to Mesh*, then keep your meshes selected and right click > *Convert to > Curve*